# How to play video in google Cardboard view in Android?

Tags: android, video, video-player, google-cardboard

I want to create a video player that can play 2D videos in a Cardboard view using android studio.

I don't know if it is possible or not? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are going to render the output to a SurfaceView, yes it is possible. you have to apply proper projection to your camera object.